# how to write proper query in cakephp 3.7 to get the data of a column and display list of items in a drop down

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I am trying to fetch the list of city_name (column) from my table Cities and display that list into my dropdown

I write the following code in my controller method

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;


class PrimeUsersController extends AppController
{


    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->viewBuilder()->setlayout('primewishsLayout');
        $this->loadModel("Cities");
        $this->loadModel("States");
        $this->loadModel("Users");

    }


    public function addnew()
    {
        // $this->autoRender=false;
        $this->set('title',"Add User/Company");
        $digits_needed=10;
        $random_number=''; // set up a blank string
        $count=0;
        while ( $count < $digits_needed ) 
        {
            $random_digit = mt_rand(0, 9);            
            $random_number .= $random_digit;
            $count++;
        }
        $this->set("rendomReg",$random_number);
            // $view=$this->States->find()->toArray();
            // print_r($view);
            // city list 
            $fieds = array('Cities.city_name');
            $city = $this->Cities->find()->select(['city_name'])->enableHydration(false)->toList();
            // print_r($city);die;
            $this->set(compact('city'));

    }

}
```

and this is my dropdown where I want to show my item list in addnew.ctp

```
<div class="col-md-3 pl-1">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>City:</label>
                        <?php 

echo  $this->Form->control('City',array(
    'options' => $city,
    'value'=>$option,
    'required'=>'required',
    'class'=>'form-control',
    'label'=>false,
    'default' => $option['select'] 
    ));
?>
 </div>
                    </div>
```

I am able to fetch the list but when I click on dropdown the list display like this:-
1
 Kanpur
2
 Lucknow
3
 Delhi

please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

According to Cakephp

> CakePHP provides a simple to use method for generating ‘lists’ of
>   data. It is often useful to generate an associative array of data from your application’s data. For example, this is very useful when creating  elements.

So to get the list of cities you can use `list` in your find query. This will give you an associative array of id and city name from your cities table.

> PrimeUsersController.php

```
 $city = $this->Cities->find('list')->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',    // specify column name that you used used as city id in cities table
        'valueField' => 'city_name' // specify column name that you used used as city name in cities table
    ])->toArray();

$this->set(compact('city'));
```

> addnew.ctp

```
$this->Form->select(       
                        'city',
                        $city,
                        ['required'=>'required',
                        'class'=>'form-control',
                        'label'=>false,
                        'empty' => 'Select City']
               );
```

[Cakephp -> Retrieving Data & Results Sets -> Finding Key/Value Pairs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)

Hope this will help!

Comment: I tried that but it's giving me a list of numbers in ascending order

Comment: @mohammadarif can you please share your table structure?

Comment: @mohammadarif it seems you have used city_name in your table. I have modified the answer for that. Please check my answer again.

Comment: @mohammadarif Welcome...Don't forget to accept the answer. it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
               $this->Form->select(       
                        'city',
                        $city,
                        ['required'=>'required',
                        'class'=>'form-control',
                        'label'=>false,
                        'default' => ':Select:']
               );
```

More instructions: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#common-options-for-specific-controls